# VBA Ultimate rounding

Tags: vba, math, excel

I've read much about rounding in Excel. I found out that VBA's Round() function uses "Bankers rounding" while Application.WorksheetFunction.Round() uses more or less "normal" rounding. But it didn't help me to understand this:

```
? Round(6.03499,2)
 6.03
```

Why? I want to see 6.04, not 6.03! The trick is that

```
? Round(Round(6.03499,3),2)
 6.04
```

I thought a bit and developed a subroutine like this:

```
Option Explicit
Function DoRound(ByVal value As Double, Optional ByVal numdigits As Integer = 0) As Double
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim res As Double
   res = value
   For i = 10 To numdigits Step -1
       res = Application.Round(res, i)
   Next i
   DoRound = res
End Function
```

It works fine.

```
? DoRound(6.03499,2)
  6.04
```

But it is not cool. Is there any built-in *normal* rounding in Excel?

Comment: Why do you expect 6.04 from Round(6.03499,2)?

Comment: because I expect that rounding begins from the end of number and goes to the beginning of the number, ie: 6.03499 -> 6.035 -> 6.04 (now stop, I asked for two numbers) -> 6.0 -> 6 (if you'd like to go further). This is what I was taught in school (or how I remember it)

Comment: Which of `6.03` and `6.04` is `6.03499` closer to?

Comment: no offence @GusRustam but you are misunderstanding the basics concept of rounding numbers. The way you want to round up numbers does not exist even if it did it wouldn't provide good results because you couldnt say  `6.49 = 7` which is not true. `6.49` never `=` `7`

Comment: No offense, mehow, but I do realize that 6.49 is not equal to 7.

Comment: @GusRustam 6.03499 rounded to 2dp is 6.03 ...I assumed this was **normal** maths.  Obviously [this Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding) goes to quite some depth but worth having a flick through.

Comment: @whytheq, yes, that's right, I can see it now. I was misled by the fact that two consequtive roundings by one digit can give answer different from one rounding by two digits.

Comment: @GusRustam no worries - I can see that you were sort of working along the line from right to left rounding each number - but you can ignore most of the number and just look at the one to the right of the digit you want to round.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you round `6.03499` to 3 digits it will be `6.035` - which is correct.
If you round `6.03499` to 2 digits it will be `6.03`  - which is correct

However - the example where you first round to 3 digits, then to 2 is also correct, by the following statement:
`Round(6.03499, 3)` gives 6.035
`Round(6.035, 2)` gives 6.04

If you want `Round(6.03499, 2)` to give 6.04 you have to use `Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp`

Comment: If you round 6.03499 to 2 digits it will be 6.03 - which is correct. Are you sure? I expect that rounding begins from the end of number and goes to the beginning of the number, ie: 6.03499 -> 6.035 -> 6.04 (now stop, I asked for two numbers) -> 6.0 -> 6 (if you'd like to go further)

Comment: @GusRustam Yes: 6.03499 to 2 digits is 6.03. Since it is .00499 from 6.03, and .00501 from 6.04. Round to 2 returns the 2-digit value, closest to the original value.
RoundUp returns the **next** 2-digit value after the original value

Comment: RoundUp doesn't solve my problem, but at the same time I think your answer is really correct. Thanks!

Comment: RoundUp(6.03499, 2) returns 6.04 on my Excel install. RoundUp(6, 2) returns 6.
How does this not solve your answer?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, RoundUp solves the problem for 6.03499. It is just not suitable for me for other reasons, but it is a good way to round 6.03499 to 6.04

Answer (score 1):

Rounding 6.0349 to two decimals is just not 6.04 hence, no, there is no such function.
Round up will round anything up. Hence, 6.0000000001 will also become 7 if you round to 0 decimals.